# hibernate search multiple spatial restrictions

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

I have two different tiers of data where tier 1 can be available nationally and tier 2 can be available up to a maximum of a 150 miles. To add to the complication I use facets as well.

My question is how can I do multiple spacial filters?

If this is a function unavailable to hibernate-search, is there a way to provide the distance from the origin on each result and exclude the results from there?

**EDIT**

I added an answer below that I believe works, but at the cost of having add additional long/lat fields. If anybody can improve upon it, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the only way to handle this is with 2 locations tied to the record and the following code query / entity code.

Query

```
    BooleanQuery luceneQuery = new BooleanQuery();

    org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = qb.spatial()
            .onField("location")
            .within(3000, Unit.KM)
            .ofLatitude(_lat)
            .andLongitude(_long)
            .createQuery();
    luceneQuery.add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);

    query = qb.spatial()
            .onField("location2")
            .within(100, Unit.KM)
            .ofLatitude(_lat)
            .andLongitude(_long)
            .createQuery();
    luceneQuery.add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);

    FullTextQuery jpaQuery =
            fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Book.class);

    return jpaQuery.list();
```

Entity

```
private Double latitude;

private Double longitude;

private Double latitude2;

private Double longitude2;

@Spatial(name = "location", spatialMode = SpatialMode.RANGE)
public Coordinates getLocation() {
    return new Coordinates() {
        @Override
        public Double getLatitude() {
            return latitude;
        }

        @Override
        public Double getLongitude() {
            return longitude;
        }
    };
}

@Spatial(name = "location2", spatialMode = SpatialMode.RANGE)
public Coordinates getLocation2() {
    return new Coordinates() {
        @Override
        public Double getLatitude() {
            return latitude2;
        }

        @Override
        public Double getLongitude() {
            return longitude2;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your requirements, but it sounds like you actually want to also index a keyword "tier" with value "1" or "2". Then you need only one pair of Coordinates, and you'd use BooleanClause.Occur.MUST to do something like (tier=1 && within 3000KM) OR (tier=2 && within 100KM)

Comment: @Sanne tier 1 and 2 were just used in my example to describe the types of inventory I have on my site, but does not actually exist as a keyword. Some of my inventory comes directly from our site and others come from partners. If a user wants to view inventory within a 3000 mile radius, inventory coming directly from our site can be shown, but I must limit the partner inventory to only a 150 mile radius of the entered zip code. If the users selects 25 miles, then the two would match.

Comment: @Sanne now hopefully with that described better, I could always flag the tier 2 inventory as partner inventory and do as your describing above, but how would I use the BooleanClause with the two flags? Thanks

Comment: @Sanne any chance you could provide an example?